# Play framework suitability for websites and web apps

Tags: playframework

In my opinion, there are 2 types of web applications: Websites and web applications (with more forms and tables than text and images...  ) .

I find it easier to create dynamic forms and tables with sorting, searching  etc with a component framework (apache wicket) . I also find it easier to create websites with play framework.

Considering my rough distinction between websites and web applications, can i say that play is more suitable for websites (the kind that php, rails ... were meant for)  than business web applications (think of a web based accounting application with a lot of tables, forms ...)

Comment: It Depends (tm). Wicket eschews RAD features (scaffolding and other code / runtime UI generation) in favour of making involved stateful behaviour easier. If you have few entities with a complex UI, a component framework is better. If you have many entities with mostly CRUD operations, a framework with scaffolding is better. I've seen "business" applications of both types.

Comment: This is too subjective for Stack Overflow. You might try http://programmers.stackexchange.com, which allows much more subjective questions, but I don't see why [your existing thread on the Play! mailing list](http://groups.google.com/group/play-framework/browse_thread/thread/cd76278b0987f4a4) isn't sufficient.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the thread on the Play group, as pointed to by @TJ has already answered your question, but for completeness, the general opinion, and mine also, is that Play is both suited for web sites and web apps.

Whilst Play does make writing websites in Java a lot easier, this really is a secondary function of why it was built. It was built to make building web applications in Java easier, because the J2EE stack was too bloated for the needs of the Play developers.

Here are some reasons why I think play was built, and works well, as a web application platform

- JPA integration, without the hassle
- Memcache out of the box
- Excellent error handling in development
- No more stop, deploy, restart cycle (which was never an issue for JSP only)
- Easy Long-polling/websocket integration
- Modules for Spring / CRUD / Security

I have seen a mixture of WebApps and Websites built with Play, and I myself have built both web apps and web sites. Play would be my first choice for most web projects now, and I have not found any major use case where Play restricts what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 3):

Play is not perfect but it's a real advance in the Java world with respect to web app development. I still wonder why nobody decided to do this kind of stuff sooner.

2years ago, I had almost decided to consider Java as lost for web developments. I had tried PHP/Python/Grails and felt it really fitted web development better than any Java EE web frameworks: more productive, easier to learn, develop and maintain and less resources required with general better results in term of graphical aspect. Java EE frameworks work yes but how many developers and time and tools do you need to do so basic things such as forms doing CRUD stuff?

Then I've discovered Play and since this time, I think Java can be a good web platform again. Play is lightweight enough for the web layer and you still can use all those great opensource production-ready frameworks from the Java world. Moreover, you can code in Java and don't need to switch to Groovy. There is still the question of the web page templating engine naturally. Play provided Groovy templating which is not really satistying. There are other engines: Japid, Cambridge for ex. Scala templating is really promising because it's a compiled one. There is no solution within Java for this. Java does not target this topic at all.

Intrigued by Scala tempaltes and grateful to great Play! Scala integration and also being a senior Java developer being more and more disappointed by global Java inertia, I began discovering Scala which provides a very very powerful alternative to Java in the JVM. Scala is really mature and provides features that will never appear in Java even in 10 years. I'm not still sure that a basic Java developer could easily switch to Scala because Scala is a advanced language that allows writing things in many ways and not one or 2 like Java. You can write Scala as you write Java but it's so much more powerful that you feel quickly it's a pity doing so. Nevertheless, as any advanced language, it requires being more strict in your coding policy if you don't want to end into writing incomprehensible code IMO (it's the same in C++ and I don't speak about functional languages). Anyway, for a senior developer, let me tell you that it's much more intellectually satisfying to achieve a piece of code in Scala than in Java... it's a fact ;)

Incoming Play2.0 is also really promising... 
I believe Java+Web can be something else than the following "caricature" vicious circle:"write tags, write beans, write JPA, write XML/annotations everywhere, redeploy, wait, wait, test... 10pages of exceptions... rewrite tags, rewrite code, launch debugger, redeploy, wait, wait, test... debug... oh no: bug not in code but in tag... stuck......" ;)... At least, in Play, you remove the "wait, wait", the "xml/annotations everywhere" and JPA is not required (ok you can also choose something else in Java EE) and the tag bugs also (ok you can have other bugs but anyway, it gives another point of view and it's good sometimes)

Answer (score 2):

Play is for me in the same bag as Ruby on Rails and Django but 
 better :-) I'm developing rather complex apllications with Spring and 
 JSF 2.0 (PrimeFaces) and I think it is good choice. I tried Vaadin (on 
 GWT) but the complex UI made client code so heavy, that it kills 
 Firefox on some computers, and works rather slow in Chrome and Opera. 
 That makes me not trust GWT. I won't use Play here either - JSF does 
 lot for me. On the other hand I'd never try to write public website 
 with JSF2. Play is great here!

Answer (score 1):

I've used play for a small application where only a user interface and a database was required and it seems to be quite fast to develop and use. However in situations where you have a large batch component that needs to runs outside of a web/app container and a small UI component i don't see play as a good option. Basically play doesn't allow you to reuse the model outside the container and hence in this situation you would need write or map the database twice in  both the batch the ui application creating duplication and maintenance issues.

I think that in this situation using the traditional layered approach where you have a service layer that can be reused by both the UI and the batch makes sense (e.g.the DAOs in the service layer are written one and reused). Please let me know if you disagree but does anyone have any guiding principals where the play framework should be used and where it should NOT be used, very interested to hear people's comments.

Comment: I never tried myself, but I think you can use your models outside the container, you will just loose some helper methods provided by Model class, but nothing stops you from just putting your DAOs jars in lib folder and using them...

Comment: I use Siena (and develop it also :) ) and I can use my models outside Play because I don't depend on anything from Play basically. But I agree that, if you use play model facilities, you're stuck to using play! as those models require runtime enhancement!